# ccavenue integration in ionic android with php

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ccavenue

Iframe solution is not working for https links.

Need to use RSA key encryption method provided by ccavenue mobile integration KIT.

Use the non-seamless mobile kit integration of php.

Add inappbrowser in application to visualize the ccavenue response.

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

After successful installation write the following code in the controller -

```
$scope.data = {
    orderId: 1,
    amount: 1,
};

$scope.ref = null;
$scope.getStateSecondWindow = function() 
{
    $scope.ref.executeScript(
        {code: "localStorage.getItem('isCloseSelf')"},
        function(data)
        {
            if (data == 'yes')
            {
                $scope.ref.close();
            } 
        }
    );
}
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
    $scope.ref = window.open(CONFIG.BASE_URL + 'getRSA.php?orderId=' +     $scope.data.orderId + '&amount=' + $scope.data.amount,'_blank','location=no');
    $scope.ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {  });
    $scope.ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    setInterval($scope.getStateSecondWindow, 5000);
    });
    $scope.ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {  });
}
```

Refer the link for php code: https://github.com/manjitlatthe/ionic-php-ccavenue-integration